# Loss of data while writing a pandas dataframe to CSV using to_csv with index = False in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a pandas dataframe that has just a single column with 2k rows. I want a csv file with all the 2k rows of dataframe without the index.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(test_label)
my_df.columns = ['Names']
my_df.to_csv('/Users/neeru/Desktop/dats/test1.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

While using the above code, I get around 1.7k rows in the saved csv file whereas when I make the `index = True`, I get all the 2k rows along with the index.

What should I do to get a csv file with a single column containing all rows without indexes?

P.S: I have just started using pandas.

Comment: Hmmm, I think `my_df.to_csv('/Users/neeru/Desktop/dats/test1.csv', index = False`) should work. If check output data manually, see difference? Or maybe there is different encoding only, but data are same.

Comment: I see different number of rows in the csv files (one where index = False and other where index = True). I'll check with the encoding once. Thanks.

Comment: Can you identify which rows are exactly missing? Perhaps their values will give you a good hint.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am getting the same issue

Comment: @RajveerParikh : The issue I faced was with the encoding of the file. I used the appropriate encoding, and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Got still the same issue, tried some encodings but didn't work. @abi To what did you change it exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.

I was saving the dataframe with the right arguments, like so:

```
df.to_csv(mask_path + df_train_label["id"][idx] + ".csv",
    index=False,
    header=False,)
```

My problem was that you also need to say `header=None` when you read the CSV file you just saved.

`df_mask = pd.read_csv(mask_path + id + ".csv", header=None)`